# push not working in mongoose/mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Trying to create a simple system where users can review books but I keep getting an error of "push" is undefined. I've tried to push new reviews to the db many times but failed every time.

I have a mongoose model:

```
var WorkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    workType: String,
    length: Number,
    ageRange: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    manuscriptText: String,
    workRating: [
        {
            reviewerName: String,
            critique: String,
            date: Date
        }
    ],
    ratingNumber: [Number],
    ratingSum: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Here is my review post with all the commented out failed code:

```
// post route for getting the review
router.post('/:id', function(req, res) {

    var critique = req.body.critique;
    var reviewerName = req.user.username;

    // find the right work associated with the critique
    Work.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundWork) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {

            // foundWork.workRating.reviewerName.push(reviewerName);
            // foundWork.workRating.critique.push(critique);
            // foundWork.workRating.date.push(Date());
            // foundWork.save();

            //     });
            // }
            // foundWork.update(
            //     {$push: {workRating: }
            //     }
            // );
            // {
            //     $push: {
            //         workRating: {
            //             reviewerName: reviewerName
            //             reviewerReview: critique
            //         }
            //         // ratingNumber: req.body.clickedValue,
            //         // $inc: {
            //         //     ratingSum req.body.clickedValue
            //         // }
            //     }
            // }
        }
    });
});
```

What the heck am I doing wrong to get these two values into that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you had a few things in the wrong places on your attempts, and there are also better ways to handle this

Simply use [`.updateOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#updateone_updateOne) directly on the model instead of [`findById()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById):

```
Work.updateOne(
  { "_id": req.params.id },
  { 
    "$push": {
      "workRating": { 
        "reviewerName": reviewerName,
        "critique": critique,
        "date": new Date()
      },
      "ratingNumber": req.body.clickedValue
    },
    "$inc": {
      "ratingSum": req.body.clickedValue
    }
  },
  function(err, response) {
   // handling
  }
)
```

[`.updateOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#updateone_updateOne) is "preferred" in the modern API when you actually mean to "update one" document. The [`update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update) method does the same thing and only updates the "first match", but it's usage is considered "deprecated" over the usage of the more "descriptive" method in your code.

Or if you really want the document to be returned [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate):

```
Work.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
  { 
    "$push": {
      "workRating": {
        "reviewerName": reviewerName,
        "critique": critique,
        "date": new Date()
      },
      "ratingNumber": req.body.clickedValue
    },
    "$inc": {
      "ratingSum": req.body.clickedValue
    }
  },
  { "new": true },             // need to get the "modified" document
  function(err, foundWork) {
    // handling
  }
)
```

You basically had modifiers in the wrong place in your attempts, and it's far more efficient to simply "update" when you don't actually need to "fetch".

Or on the "not so great" pattern of "fetch/modify/save":

```
foundWork.workRating.push({
  "reviewerName": reviewerName,
  "critique": critique,
  "date": new Date()
});
foundWork.ratingNumber.push(req.body.clickedValue);
foundWork.ratingSum = foundWork.ratinSum + 1;

foundWork.save(function(err,modifiedWork) {
  // handling
});
```

Where again you are really just attempting to `.push()` in the wrong places.

Note you can also add in your schema:

```
"date": { "type": Date, "default": Date.now }
```

Which will automatically apply that value on all operations here as mongoose will modify the update operations based on the schema setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with what you're doing. `push` is a function to add element into array and none of  `reviewerName` , `critique` or `date` is array. That's why you are seeing `.push is undefined`.

What it looks like is you are trying to  update your document with `push` an object in `workRating` array. So, this is how you do that

```
Work.update({_id :req.params.id }, {$push : {workRating : {reviewerName : "A", 
critique : "XYZ", date : "your_date"}}})
```